# Why dpes replace() method in python replace also "this" with "thare" when i try to replace "is" with "are"?

Tags: python, string, replace

I try this code:

```
print("This is it!".replace("is", "are"))
```

and i see this output:

```
"Thare are it!"
```

I try reverse this and thare code:
print("Thare are it!".replace("are", "is"))
output:
"This is it!"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqtWg.png)

Comment: Because "this" contains the string "is" which is replaced with "are".

Comment: You could try using `" is "` and `" are "` to make sure you are only replacing the standalone words.

Comment: What is the question? Please tell me you figured this out!. What could have happened? "This" turned into "Thare" when you replaced "is" by "are"....

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal `re.sub(r"\bis\b", "are",  s)` if you want to be more robust. Words could be surrounded by punctuation or at the beginning of a string-

Answer (score 1):

The `.replace()` function in python replaces all occurrences of a string with a replacement string

The string, `"This is it!"` contains 2 instances of the string `"is"` - 1 at position 2 and another at position 5

If you want to replace only the WORD 'is' with another word (strings and words are sometimes different things), try detecting `" is "`. One thing though is that the string `"That it is."` will not be replaced correctly, since `" is "` does not appear anywhere in the string, but `" is."` does.

As your string manipulation needs get more complex (not sure they will), regex is a powerful tool to match exact patterns within text that you might consider looking into

As a general rule, read the documentation for any language/method/library that you are attempting to use. A simple google search for `python replace` yields [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp), which features the note

> Note: All occurrences of the specified phrase will be replaced, if nothing else is specified.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you can use the `re` library for regular expressions to specify that "is" must be surrounded by *word boundaries* (denoted with `\b`). This will ensure that the "s" in "This" does not match.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\bis\b", "are", "This is it!")
'This are it!'
```